# CreateFile() and CopyFile() share permissions

Tags: c++, windows, file

I wrote a simple XOR crypter and need help with fixing the crypted file's sharing permissions. 
Basically, the output file from `Builder.exe` has a state of `Shared`. I have to change the file's share permissions to `Nobody` before I can run it.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm using Windows API?

This is the code for the handle that I wrote:

```
HANDLE efile = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_ALL,FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

Full source code on GitHub: https://github.com/Jyang772/XOR_Crypter

Error message:
[image]

Comment: What error code are you seeing?

Comment: @Irb 
There is no error code. Just a message saying I don't have the permissions to run the crypted file.

Comment: Don't understand is this your code huh? You should have some reason why file open access was denied.

Comment: I haven't bothered to fix this when I first wrote it. But now it's bugging me. This was written when I was first learning WinAPI.

Comment: What is the output of "efile"?

Comment: It's putting the input file data into a char buffer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44542/discussion-between--and-lrb)

Comment: Which version of windows are you using?  ACLs changes with every new version of windows.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Professional x64.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "change the file's share permissions"?  If you're writing `builder.exe` in your code, you'll have to close the handle before attempting to execute it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Right clicking the crypted file. And selecting `Share With..` `Nobody`

Comment: My system doesn't give me that menu option.  But all it can be doing is changing the ACL.  The file should be inheriting a suitable ACL from the directory, so it sounds as if the ACL for the directory is messed up.